# Keeping page layout in control updates

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have managed to create a custom renderer for `Page` in iOS that handles keyboard events and using `Element.LayoutTo()` I change the area that page renders to, and hence bring my controls into view while the keyboard is open.

The problem is once any control changes (ex. a label text changes) the page layout goes back to its original size, hiding my control underneath the keyboard. I want to know where can I intercept this effect and force the view back to its position.

I have tried to use `Element.SizeChanged` event and reset the layout to my desired values but since the layout happens this causes page flickers.

Comment: Could you please share some code about when you use "Element.LayoutTo()" and when you change your control to help me reproduce your issue.